# using dispatch_async from built framework

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, queue, dispatch-async

I am facing the strange problem with `dispatch_async`

I have two separate projects: one is for building the framework and another is for using that framework for some purposes.

I am trying to execute very simple piece of code (without any additional code even):

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    });
});
```

so if i put this `dispatch_async` to my project it works just perfect,
but if put it to some method of my framework project and build it
 and then call that method from the project which is using that framework 
then i receive `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on first `dispatch_async` line on `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue` stack

Although this `dispatch_async` will work only with `dispatch_get_main_queue()` queue

I tried to create different queues with different priorities, i tried static queues, 
and they are actually created, but `dispatch_async` crashes every time

I believe this is a problem related to some flags in build settings in my framework project, 
but unfortunately i cannot find anything what can help

UPDATE: 
I forgot to say, that this perfectly works on simulator, but does not work on the device

And here is an example of my code:

```
[[SingleTonOfFramework sharedInstance] executeRequest:@"SomeRequest"
                                              success:^(id response) {
                                                  NSLog(@"works");
                                              }];
```

SingleTonOfFramework - is a class from my framework
and this is what it does:

```
- (void) executeRequest:(id) request success:(void (^)(id response))success {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            success(@"COOL!");

        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the actual code causing the problem, there is no way to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: the code is already there, i just put this code to any method and try to call it, the problem is not in the place where i put this `dispatch_async` code

Comment: It's not that simple. I use that pattern all over my app, calling code from other frameworks. It works just fine in general. The problem must be specific to what you are doing. Therefore you must show us the actual code giving you the problem.